# NSNumberFormatter currency: "plusSign" replaces currency

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

When configuring an NSNumberFormatter in Swift the following:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(currencyCode code: String) {
        self.init()
        numberStyle = .currency
        locale = .autoupdatingCurrent
        maximumFractionDigits = 2
        positivePrefix = plusSign
        currencyCode = code
        minimumFractionDigits = 2
    }
```

it works for locales where the currency sign is at the end, e.g. `de_DE`: `12345` becomes `+1.234,00 €`. But for `de_AT` it becomes `+1.234,00` - without the `positivePrefix` it would be `€ 1.234,00`; how can I always show the sign in front (+ and -) but still keep the currency?

EDIT:

I would expect this test to fail (because the currency is missing), but it succeeds:

```
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_AT")
XCTAssertEqual(currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 0)), "+0,00")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out accounting is your rescue, change the number style

```
numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
```

and you get your expected output

Comment: In many locales, such as `en_US` this will format a negative value like `-1234.57` as `($1234.57)`  and isn't necessarily what OP and others with a similar issue would want https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/style/currencyaccounting